# Qt application not exiting, staying in memory

Tags: qt, exit

Here is the code I am having trouble with:

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
QString path = qApp->applicationDirPath();
qApp->setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false);
a.addLibraryPath(path+"/plugins");
TryQt w;
w.show();
return  a.exec();
```

This is how I am starting my Application. In the Application (TryQt) I am creating several other `QWidgets` and `Qwindows`. The problem arises when I close the application  The `QMainWindow` disappears, looks like the program exits, but it remains in the memory.  (I can see from  **Task Manager / Processes** )  . 
I am also catching the closeEvent in my TryQt program and closing every thing possible I opened in there. But still no use. Does any one has any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 5):

well, it's because you're calling

```
qApp->setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false);
```

the docs say:

> This property holds whether the
>   application implicitly quits when the
>   last window is closed.
>
> The default is true.
>
> If this property is true, the
>   applications quits when the last
>   visible primary window (i.e. window
>   with no parent) with the
>   Qt::WA_QuitOnClose attribute set is
>   closed. By default this attribute is
>   set for all widgets except for
>   sub-windows. Refer to Qt::WindowType
>   for a detailed list of Qt::Window
>   objects.

and you are for some reason setting it to false.

Comment: changing qApp->setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false); to True still not changing any thing. its not exiting the programme even though main Window has been closed.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem (except calling `qApp->setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(true);` as the previous answer suggests). I suspect one of the libraries we use doesn't clean up its thread properly and an investigation is pending, but the simplest workaround was to replace `return a.exec();` with:

```
exit(a.exec());
```